# How to add images in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm new to angular js.

I have stumbled into a problem. I am using a json for my data and not sure of how am I supposed to add the images in my code

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">

    <div class="col-md-8">

        <div ng-repeat="item in products" class="product col-md-4">

            <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
            <img ng-src="{{item.Image}}" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
            <p>
                <br>
                <button type="button" ng-click="show = !show"  class="btn btn-success">View Product</button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="add_to_cart()" class="btn btn-danger">Add To Cart</button>
                <br>
                <span><b style="color: #ff0000">Size: </b> {{item.Size}} </span>
                <span><b style="color: #ff0000">for: </b> {{item.Gender}} </span> 
                <br>
            </p>
            <div class="description" ng-show="show">{{item.description}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div id="cart" class="col-md-12">
            <div id="cart_content" class="">
            <h4>Cart:</h4>
                <table id="test" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr class="tr">
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tr" ng-repeat="pro in product">
                        <input type="hidden" name="someData" ng-value="{{pro.id}}" /> {{pro.id}}
                        <!-- <span style="display: none;">{{pro.id}}</span> -->
                        <td>{{pro.count}}</td>
                        <td>{{pro.title}}</td>
                        <td>{{pro.qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{pro.cost}}</td>
                        <td>{{pro.total}}</td>

                        <td>[<a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">X</a>]</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $http.get('json/products.json').success(function(data) {

                $scope.products = data; // get data from json       
        });

        var total = 0;
        var counter = 0;
        $scope.product = [];

        $scope.add_to_cart = function(){

            counter++;

            total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(this.item.price);

            $scope.product.push({
                id: this.item.id,
                qty: 1,
                title: this.item.title,
                cost: this.item.price,  
                total: total,
                count: counter
            });         
        }

        $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
            $scope.product.splice(index, 1);
        }

    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: simply specify the folder path inside `ng-src="{{patheHere}}"` attribute of image

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing it right. Just make sure that `item.Image` points to the correct image source. Look inside your products.json to adjust the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these.

1. Is the image src right that you get in the browser?
2. If not, make sure 'json/products.json' responses correct json data.
3. If yes, checkout full url of the image tag in the browser. The full url could be different with the expected cause of relative path.

ps. You're done right using angular js as @NicBright said.